# how to match several possible log events formats?

Tags: logstash, grok, logstash-grok

I have events from one log source which can have several known formats. As an example

```
10:45 Today is Monday
11:13 The weather is nice
12:00 The weather is cloudy
```

I can `match` each of them via

```
The weather is %{WORD:weather}
Today is %{WORD:weekday}
```

I am not yet comfortable with the format of logstash `filter`. In order to account for each of these possibilities, should I build something like

```
if message =~ "The weather is"
{
    grok {
        "match" => "The weather is %{WORD:weather}"
    }
}
if message =~ "Today is"
{
    grok {
    "match" => "Today is %{WORD:weekday}"
    }
}
```

or is there something more compact? (for instance a list of possible patterns for the events with the associated mapping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: to enumerate the patterns:

```
filter {
        grok {
                match =>  { "message" => [ "hello %{WORD:who}", "the weather is %{WORD:weather}" ] }

                }
      }
```